# When is an old check form invalid?

Tags: banking, netherlands

Can the bank refuse my check just because the check form is printed about 5 years ago and the bank now has newer checks?
The bank manager said that he will accept the check this time but next time I write a check it should be on the new check form that the bank now uses.

Comment: Did the name of the bank or the routing number change?

Comment: No, bank name, routing number and account number are the same. The size of the check is somewhat larger and the print is not the same as the new checks.That are the only differences.

Comment: Well, if he accepted it, then clearly it’s not invalid.

Comment: He said that he accepted it as a courtesy to me but he didn't have to; I think that means that he considers it invalid.

Comment: Michael, how can you conclude that? What about next time I use the same check form; is it invalid than?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: The country is Suriname in South America; a former colony from the Netherlands. The laws there, also the laws re banking, are mainly the same as the laws in the Netherlands.

Comment: @A..Lowe If it was invalid then he would not have accepted it. I would imagine that even in South America, there are no grey lines between a valid Check and an invalid one. It’s like saying “that passport is old, but I’ll accept it this time.”

Comment: @Michael difference being that passports have an expiration date.

Comment: @RonJohn Passports change designs as well. Same thing with cash.

Comment: @Michael since passports expire, writing a check on an old format *not* the same as trying to use an old passport.

Answer (score 1):

A check is valid if the recipient, the depositing bank, and the issuing bank are all willing to accept it. In the US it is generally accepted that you could hand-write a check on pretty much anything assuming it contains enough information on it for the depositing bank to determine the issuing bank, and for the issuing bank to determine your account. If the check uses an irregular form (e.g. very old, hand-written, huge piece of cardboard, toilet paper, rock, pig, etc.), then whether or not it will be accepted and also honored is most likely going to be taken on a case by case basis by all involved parties.

My advice is if you are using an irregular form, include your mobile number on the check so the bank(s) can call you to verify it if they wish. As the recipient of an irregular form check, I would recommend skipping your own bank and taking the check directly to the issuing bank.

All that being said, to answer your specific question:

> Can the bank refuse my check just because the check form is printed about 5 years ago and the bank now has newer checks?

Yes, the bank can refuse *any* check that they wish, whether irregular or not, though typically they would only refuse it if they questioned the validity of it. Presumably they wouldn't normally refuse a regular check since that would annoy their customers!

Answer (score 0):

> next time I write a check it should be on the new check form that the bank now uses.

I call BS, since the bank must also accept checks from other institutions.

Comment: RonJohn, What is BS?

Comment: RonJohn, what is BS which you advise me o call?

Comment: RonJohn, how can the bank accept checks fro other institutions, the check is after all an order to the bank to pay the check amount to the beneficiary.

Comment: @A..Lowe what I mean is wanting to deposit a check from a different bank.

Comment: @A..Lowe  BS = bullsh*t

Comment: @A..Lowe I think you misunderstood mkennedy's comment. He was simply explaining that the acronym BS in the answer stands for "bullsh*t". The expression "I call BS" in the answer means that RonJohn believes that the bank's statement is just some kind of pretext.